# Why $\mu_1$ satisfy the following property?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Consider
$$
\mu_1(E) = \sup\left\{\mu(F);\; F\subseteq E,\,F\in \mathcal{M}\; \text{and}\; \mu(F)<\infty\right\},
$$
for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$.

> - Why $\mu_1$ is well defined?
> - Why for all $E \in\mathcal{M}$ with $\mu_1(E) = \infty$, there exists $F \in\mathcal{M}$ with $F \subset E$ and $0 < \mu_1(F) < \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your second question suggests that $\mu_1:\mathcal P(X)\to[0,\infty]$. But, on $[0,\infty]$ the supremum of any of its subsets is well defined.
2. By definition, if $\mu_1(E)>0$, there must be an $F\in\mathcal M$ with $F\subseteq E$ and $0<\mu(F)<\infty$, since the supremum of the empty set is $0$. And observe that $\mu_1(M)=\mu(M)$ for any $M\in\mathcal M$ with finite measure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Could you please explain me why if $\mu_1(E)>0$, there must be an $F\in\mathcal M$ with $F\subseteq E$ and $0<\mu(F)<\infty$?

Comment: If there is no such $F$, the set $\{F\mid F\subseteq E, \, \mu(F) <\infty\} $ is empty, and the supremum of that in $[0,\infty] $ is $0$.